# Jenkins server --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 not working

Tags: jenkins, nginx-reverse-proxy

recently I installed Jenkins server, and wanted to hide it behind Nginx proxy.
My Nginx proxy works fine and I read to restrict Jenkins to `127.0.0.1:8080` therefore, I edited the config file `/etc/default/jenkins` and put below line of code:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"
```

After restarting jenkins, I still have access to Jenkins on port `8080`

Environment:

Ubuntu 20.04

OpenJDK 11

Jenkins 2.332.1

Netstat output:

```
    sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2313/java

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      970/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      708/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      946/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      757/cupsd

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      970/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      946/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      757/cupsd
```

P.S. I tried on EC2/Amazom linux 2, same issue

Comment: For a quick fix I edited `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` and added `Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1"`. which worked, but it does not seem to be best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Jenkins version 2.332.1, which you indicated you are running, Jenkins made the switch from running as a service using classic SysV init scripts over to fully integrating with systemd on Linux distributions that support it, which includes Ubuntu 20.04.  I don't see any signs that the systemd unit file for Jenkins ever parses `/etc/default/jenkins`, meaning those settings are only parsed by the SysV init script, which would explain why your configuration had no effect there.

As you found, setting the environment variable in `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` indeed works, but your instinct is absolutely correct that it is not best practice to directly edit the unit file managed by the packaging system.  As with most things in Linux, the `/etc` directory is where administrators are meant to put their configuration files, and `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are reserved for the package manager, so luckily systemd is no exception to this and provides a mechanism for such changes.

Systemd has the concept of "drop-in" directories where you can place ".conf" files with partial systemd unit configurations whose directives will override those in the main unit file.  From the [systemd.unit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

> Along with a unit file `foo.service`, a "drop-in" directory `foo.service.d/` may exist. All files with the suffix ".conf" from this directory will be merged in the alphanumeric order and parsed after the main unit file itself has been parsed. This is useful to alter or add configuration settings for a unit, without having to modify unit files. Each drop-in file must contain appropriate section headers.

###### Here's how I set up Jenkins 2.332.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 using a systemd drop-in override to bind the listener to 127.0.0.1:

Verify Jenkins is running and listening on all addresses/interfaces:

```
$ sudo ss -tlnp | grep 8080
LISTEN    0         50               *:8080               *:*        users:(("java",pid=2688,fd=116))
```

Create a systemd drop-in directory for Jenkins:

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
```

Create an override file using your favorite editor.  You can name it whatever you want as long as it has a `.conf` extension.  Personally, I prefer something descriptive and to begin with a number so that I can control the lexicographic order in which the files are parsed, should I ever end up with multiple override files.  Given that, I created a file `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/50-listen-address-override.conf` with the following content:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1"
```

Now, all we have to do is tell systemd that we made some changes we want it to reparse:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And we can restart Jenkins to give it its new config:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

If we verify our work, we can now see that Jenkins is only bound to 127.0.0.1:

```
$ sudo ss -tlnp | grep 8080
LISTEN   0        50          [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:8080          *:*       users:(("java",pid=31636,fd=116))
```

For what it's worth, you can also use the command `systemctl edit jenkins` to create the override, and systemd will create the drop-in directory and override file automatically for you and drop you into your default editor to write the file contents, however it does not give you the freedom to choose your own name for the override file, giving it instead a generic name of `override.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

While it won't hurt to restrict port 8080 in an AWS environment there really isn't a reason to worry about it.  You'll want to setup a [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html) to your server so everything is blocked except for maybe port 22 (ssh), port 80 (http) and port 443 (https).  You can do this through the AWS console.

To do this, go to the AWS console and select EC2 and then your instance.  In the middle of the page is the "Security" tab.  From there you can create a security group to determine what traffic you allow in and out.

In this way no one can connect to *any* ports that you don't allow in.  You're not currently using https it looks like and so you may want to leave out port 443 until you're ready.

Comment: You are right in case of AWS/Ec2 but I am using it in VMware.